# How to exclude double values from list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with 10k+ records. These records contains phonenumbers of clients. Some of the records have the same phonenumber in them. I am now looking for way to only show the records where the phonenumber is unique in the whole file. (So not delete the duplicates, where one of the double values stays in the file, but really delete or hide the records where the phonenumber is not unique in the file).

So I want to delete all the rows where the phonenumbers are colored red (see example below).

[image]

Comment: Use a helper column, maybe with some easy formula like `COUNTIFS`, delete those that occur more than once. Btw, you have highlighted two of the same numbers, however `ID` and `NAME` might make this actually an unique record. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you post this as an answer. Because this solved my problem and was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:

Use a helper column, maybe with some easy formula like `COUNTIFS`, delete those that occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the new dynamic arrays: `UNIQUE` (you have the check if the function is available to you already - it is pretty new, but I got it recently on all my devices).

If you want to display the items that appear **exactly once**, you can set the `[exactly_once]` parameter to `TRUE` and you type this formula into cell `D1`:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:C7,,TRUE)
```